# Inaccuracy of 1 dimensional FFTW3 derivatives in C++ despite using zero padding and 1/2 filter

Tags: c++

I am trying to check if my 1D fftw3 implementation is right by testing for the first derivative of a sinusoidal input sample. The original sample size is nX and I've padded it with zeros on both ends of the sample such that the new sample size is 3 * nX (nX3).

The accuracy without the padding wasn't good for the derivatives and it got worse with higher derivatives, making zero padding seem necessary.

However, the padded sample input has accuracy much lesser than that of the non-padded one. The accuracy was checked by comparing the first order derivative of sample input (sin(x)), real(out[]),  with its analytical value, cos(x). The code is shown below.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<complex>
    #include<fftw3.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        int i,ir,nX;
        nX = 16; 

        int nX3, nX2; //padded array dimension = nX3
        nX3 = 3*nX; 
        nX2=2*nX; 

        double Nd = (double)nX3;
        int id;
        double pi = M_PI;

        std::complex<double> *in, *out;

        in = (complex<double>*)malloc(nX3*sizeof(complex<double>));
        if(in==NULL) { cout<<"inalloc error\n"<<endl;}
        out = (complex<double>*)malloc(nX3*sizeof(complex<double>));
        if(out==NULL) { cout<<"outalloc error\n"<<endl;}

        fftw_complex *bt; 
        bt = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*nX3); 

        fftw_plan p, q; 

        p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(nX3, reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(in), bt, FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);
        q = fftw_plan_dft_1d(nX3, bt, reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(out), FFTW_BACKWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);

        for(i=0;i<nX3;i++)
        { 
            in[i] = {0.0,0.0}; //initialising padded input array
        }

        for(i=nX;i<nX2;i++)
        { 
            double id = (double)(i-nX)*pi/nX;
            //sinusoidal input in the central square of the padded array (3 squares)
            //varies in 'i' direction
            in[i] = complex<double>(sin(id),0.0); 
            //cout<<"i\t"<<i-nX<<"\t"<<in[i]<<endl;

        }

        fftw_execute(p); //fourier transform

        double kx; 
        int x1; 
        kx = 2.0*pi/(double)nX3; 
        double kx1;

        for(i=0;i<nX;i++)
        {
            double btr(0.0), btc(0.0); //temporary variables

            id=i+nX; 

            if(id<nX3/2) //1/2 filter
            {
                x1 = id;
            } 
            else if(id==nX3/2)
            {
                x1 = 0; 
            } 
            else
            {  
                x1 = id-nX3;
            }

            kx1=kx*(double)x1; 
            //complex first derivative array 'bt[id]'
            btr = -1.0*kx1*bt[id][1]; //real part
            btc = kx1*bt[id][0]; //complex part
            bt[id][0] = btr;
            bt[id][1] = btc;

        }   

        fftw_execute(q); //inverse fourier transform


        for(i=0;i<nX;i++)
        { 
            //input sample varies only in the i direction, hence out[i+nX] should be identical for all 'y' and 'z' points inside the central cube  at a specific value of 'i'            
            double id = (double)i*pi/nX; 

            double c = cos(id); //analytical value of first derivative for comparison with 'out[i+NX]'

            cout<<"i\t"<<i<<"\t"<<c<<"\t"<<real(out[i+nX])/Nd<<endl;    
            //analytical value 'c' compared with fftw3 result, 'out'
            //normalising 'out[i+nX]' by dividing it by volume of padded array dimension nX3
        } 

        free(bt); 
        free(in); 
        free(out);  
        fftw_destroy_plan(p); 
        fftw_destroy_plan(q);

    }
```

Comment: How are you determining accuracy?

Comment: I am comparing it with the analytical values for now. For example, cos(x) is the first derivative of sin(x), and I compare cos(x) with the output array 'dx[i]' . I am not using any statistical test for determining accuracy right now as it didn't seem to make sense. The result I got without padding had a percentage error of about 2% ( dx[i]-cos(x))/cos(x) ) at the mid-values of the sample. The end points of the sample had an error percentage of about 80%. Padding the input array 'in[]' has made things much worse instead of better. Every value has an error percentage of more than 50% .

Comment: Also, I would really appreciate it if you could tell me why this question got downvoted. Pointing out some of the flaws in this will prevent me from making the same mistakes again. Thanks :)

Comment: I can only talk about one of the downvotes ;)  For me, it's the combination of a very large block of code ("very" in Stack Overflow terms - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and an imprecise problem statement (i.e. what you mean by "accuracy", etc.)  If you improve the question, I'll gladly remove my downvote.

Comment: Hello, I have edited it.  It should hopefully be a bit better. Scaled down from 3D to 1D, and removed some unnecessary loops and variables.

Comment: Thanks for the removal!